# Find one document in mongodb with a preference toward "Starts With"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I have a mongo database of names.

Let's say it looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513a18c1f9e9b5c19fd80014"), "name" : "Mary Sue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513a18d9f9e9b5c19fd80015"), "name" : "Tammy Sue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513a18e4f9e9b5c19fd80016"), "name" : "Sueellen" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513a18eaf9e9b5c19fd80017"), "name" : "Ellen" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513a195af9e9b5c19fd80018"), "name" : "Sue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513a1ccaf9e9b5c19fd80019"), "name" : "Eddie" }
```

I would like to be able to perform a (case-insensitive) query for a single result which will prioritize the return value like so:
If "name" *starts with* my string, then return the first alphabetical "starts with" result.
Otherwise, if name *contains* my string, then return the first alphabetical result.

Examples:
  A search for `/sue/i` should return "Sue".
  A search for `/e/i` should return "Eddie".
  A search for `/len/i` should return "Ellen".
  A search for `/ue/i` should return "Mary Sue".

Is it possible to do this without either doing 2 separate calls (one for `/^len/i`, then for `/len/i` if I got 0 results), or finding every match and parsing the results myself?

I happen to be using node.js and mongoose here, but a generic mongo answer would also be fine so I can understand the concepts.

Comment: No, not really, as I believe you want, find Best Matches (Starts exactly with), if no best matches, find "OK" matches. The 2nd search will be very intensive as all names will need to be matched (while the first could use an index potentially). This type of search might be better for a full text search engine in terms of performance. Maybe. :)

Comment: For this project I don't care about performance. The universe of names is small enough that a "full" search, and programmatically doing it on the client side, is fine.  But I thought there might be some kind of map-reduce or aggregation trick, or even a "name" for what I'm trying to do. I'm still learning about database terminology in general (and starting with nosql databases, which might be odd...)

Answer (score -1):

This is just a matter of the right regexp. You can specify multiple matches in a regexp. It's worth having a look at http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/ and get a deeper understanding of the regexp. OR download 2.4 from www.mongodb.org and try out the new text index option

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#text-indexes

Comment: I come from a perl background; I am pretty well-versed with regexes. The regex itself would be trivial; I'm asking about getting the "best" match as a single result, basically from findOne().

I will read up in the features of 2.4 to see if those would help, though.